# Mongodb: db undefined on connect

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to access mongodb through native driver.

When i use connect method in my remote method. I am getting connected successfully but i am getting "undefined" as db object

Purpose : Getting all fields name from collection.

```
Activation.getUserFields = function (id, callbackFn) {
        Activation.app.dataSources.mongoConnector.connect(function (errconnect, mdb) {
            if (errconnect) callbackFn(errconnect, {});
            else {
                console.log('mdb', mdb);
                var mr = mdb.runCommand({
                    "mapreduce": "Visit",
                    "map": function () {
                        for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
                    },
                    "reduce": function (key, stuff) { return null; },
                    "out": "Visit" + "_keys"
                });

                mdb[mr.result].distinct("_id").toArray(function (errFields, docFields) {
                    if (errFields) callbackFn(errFields, {});
                    else {
                        callbackFn(null, docFields);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
};
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Please post the error message you're seeing

Comment: Not getting any error message.Just getting mdb undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In LoopBack You can access Model and Collection by :

Plz try :

```
const ActivationCollection = Activation.getDataSource().connector.collection("Activation");
ActivationCollection.runCommand({
                "mapreduce": "Visit",
                "map": function () {
                    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
                },
                "reduce": function (key, stuff) { return null; },
                "out": "Visit" + "_keys"
            });
```

Comment: Not working. Getting `TypeError: ActivationCollection.runCommand is not a function`